# PIG how to count a number of rows in alias

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I did something like this to count the number of rows in an alias in PIG:

```
logs = LOAD 'log'
logs_w_one = foreach logs generate 1 as one;
logs_group = group logs_w_one all;
logs_count = foreach logs_group generate SUM(logs_w_one.one);
dump logs_count;
```

This seems to be too inefficient. Please enlighten me if there is a better way!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

COUNT is part of pig [see the manual](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/func.html#count)

```
LOGS= LOAD 'log';
LOGS_GROUP= GROUP LOGS ALL;
LOG_COUNT = FOREACH LOGS_GROUP GENERATE COUNT(LOGS);
```

Comment: Is it possible to count the number of rows in an alias without first grouping?

Comment: Same question. I read that `GROUP x ALL` will force a serialization in the pipeline with consequent possible slow down. Is that correct?

Comment: You have to group before counting. According to http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/func.html#count:  "COUNT requires a preceding GROUP ALL statement for global counts and a GROUP BY statement for group counts."

Comment: Does this have any sort of problem if `LOGS` is empty (zero rows)?

Answer (score 34):

Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz already answered this question a while ago, but I thought some may like this slightly more concise version.

```
LOGS = LOAD 'log';
LOG_COUNT = FOREACH (GROUP LOGS ALL) GENERATE COUNT(LOGS);
```

Answer (score 32):

Be careful, with `COUNT` your first item in the bag must not be null. Else you can use the function `COUNT_STAR` to count all rows.

Answer (score 10):

Basic counting is done as was stated in other answers, and in the pig documentation:

```
logs = LOAD 'log';
all_logs_in_a_bag = GROUP logs ALL;
log_count = FOREACH all_logs_in_a_bag GENERATE COUNT(logs);
dump log_count
```

You are right that counting is inefficient, even when using pig's builtin COUNT because this will use one reducer. However, I had a revelation today that one of the ways to speed it up would be to reduce the RAM utilization of the relation we're counting.

In other words, when counting a relation, we don't actually care about the data itself so let's use as little RAM as possible. You were on the right track with your first iteration of the count script.

```
logs = LOAD 'log'
ones = FOREACH logs GENERATE 1 AS one:int;
counter_group = GROUP ones ALL;
log_count = FOREACH counter_group GENERATE COUNT(ones);
dump log_count
```

This will work on much larger relations than the previous script and should be much faster. The main difference between this and your original script is that we don't need to sum anything.

This also doesn't have the same problem as other solutions where null values would impact the count. This will count all the rows, regardless of if the first column is null or not.

Answer (score 5):

USE COUNT_STAR

```
LOGS= LOAD 'log';
LOGS_GROUP= GROUP LOGS ALL;
LOG_COUNT = FOREACH LOGS_GROUP GENERATE COUNT_STAR(LOGS);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version with optimization. 
All the solutions above would require pig to read and write full tuple when counting, this script below just write '1'-s

```
DEFINE row_count(inBag, name) RETURNS result {
    X = FOREACH $inBag generate 1;
    $result = FOREACH (GROUP X ALL PARALLEL 1) GENERATE '$name', COUNT(X);
};
```

The use it like

```
xxx = row_count(rows, 'rows_count');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to count all the lines in a relation (dataset in Pig Latin)

This is very easy following the next steps:

```
logs = LOAD 'log'; --relation called logs, using PigStorage with tab as field delimiter
logs_grouped = GROUP logs ALL;--gives a relation with one row with logs as a bag
number = FOREACH LOGS_GROUP GENERATE COUNT_STAR(logs);--show me the number
```

I have to say it is important Kevin's point as using COUNT instead of COUNT_STAR we would have only the number of lines which first field is not null.

Also I like Jerome's one line syntax it is more concise but in order to be didactic I prefer to divide it in two and add some comment.

In general I prefer:

```
numerito = FOREACH (GROUP CARGADOS3 ALL) GENERATE COUNT_STAR(CARGADOS3);
```

over

```
name = GROUP CARGADOS3 ALL
number = FOREACH name GENERATE COUNT_STAR(CARGADOS3);
```