# What's the effective way to count rows in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig, reducers

In Pig, what is the effective way to get count? We can do a GROUP ALL, but this is given only 1 reducer. When the data size is very large,say n Terabytes, can we try multiple reducers somehow?

```
  dataCount = FOREACH (GROUP data ALL) GENERATE 
    'count' as metric,
    COUNT(dataCount) as value;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIG how to count a number of rows in alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900761/pig-how-to-count-a-number-of-rows-in-alias)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using directly a `GROUP ALL`, you could divide it into two steps. First, group by some field and count the number of rows. And then, perform a `GROUP ALL` to sum all of these counts. This way, you would be able to count the number of rows in parallel.

Note, however, that if the field you use in the first `GROUP BY` does not have duplicates, the resulting counts will all be of 1 so there wont be any difference. Try using a field that has many duplicates to improve its performance.

See this example:

```
a;1
a;2
b;3
b;4
b;5
```

If we first group by the first field, which has duplicates, the final `COUNT` will deal with 2 rows instead of 5:

```
A = load 'data' using PigStorage(';');
B = group A by $0;
C = foreach B generate COUNT(A);
dump C;
(2)
(3)
D = group C all;
E = foreach D generate SUM(C.$0);
dump E;
(5)
```

However, if we group by the second one, which is unique, it will deal with 5 rows:

```
A = load 'data' using PigStorage(';');
B = group A by $1;
C = foreach B generate COUNT(A);
dump C;
(1)
(1)
(1)
(1)
(1)
D = group C all;
E = foreach D generate SUM(C.$0);
dump E;
(5)
```

Answer (score -1):

I just dig a bit more in this topic, and it seems you don't have to afraid that a single reducer will have to process enormous amount of data if you're using an up-to-date pig version. 
The algebraic UDF-s will handle the COUNT smart, and it's calculated on the mapper. So the reducer just have to deal with the aggregated data (counts/mapper). 
I think it's introduced in 0.9.1, but [0.14.0](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/udf.html) definitely has it

> **Algebraic Interface**
>
> An aggregate function is an eval function that takes a bag and returns
>   a scalar value. One interesting and useful property of many aggregate
>   functions is that they can be computed incrementally in a distributed
>   fashion. We call these functions algebraic. COUNT is an example of an
>   algebraic function because we can count the number of elements in a
>   subset of the data and then sum the counts to produce a final output.
>   In the Hadoop world, this means that the partial computations can be
>   done by the map and combiner, and the final result can be computed by
>   the reducer.

*But my previous answer was definitely wrong:*

> In the grouping you can use the `PARALLEL n` keyword this set the
>   number of reducers.
>
> > Increase the parallelism of a job by specifying the number of reduce
> >     tasks, n. The default value for n is 1 (one reduce task).

Comment: `GROUP ALL` generates one group, and a group must be in only one reducer. Therefore `PARALLEL` will not help in this situation.

Comment: And what about the default parallel? `SET default_parallel 20;` ?

Comment: Each group is executed in only ONE node, it does not matter the level of parallelism, the default parallel, etc. If you use `group all`, you have a huge group in only one node no matter the level of parallelism.

Comment: Probably the default parallel doesn't work for the same reason as Balduz said. But here I found something: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html#parallel  `pig.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` - Defines the number of input bytes per reduce; default value is 1000*1000*1000 (1GB).

Comment: Again... each group is executed in one node and node only. As you can see in the official documentation, a `group all` is performed in only ONE node no matter the parallel level, since it will replace it with 1: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html#GroupByConstParallelSetter

Comment: Yes it's clearly mention this for the `PARALLEL` keyword. Now I'm get curious so I'll try what the `pig.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` does in this case :) (probably you're right and it also doesn't help... we'll see)

Comment: No success, it does nothing in this case. (tested) You're right Balduz.