# how to count number of rows in a relation in pig

Tags: count, apache-pig

I have a relation in pig named 'A'

```
(name:gender:zip-code)
(x:m:1234)
(y:f:1234)
(z:m:1245)
(s:f:1235)
```

How can I get the number of rows in relation A?

I want to get the result as 4.

Comment: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/func.html#count
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900761/pig-how-to-count-a-number-of-rows-in-alias

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your relation is named A.

```
B = GROUP A ALL;
B_COUNT = FOREACH B GENERATE COUNT(A);
DUMP B_COUNT;
```